Hey guys is it possible to change immutable metadata? Or to change the coin that’s under a market id?
I have a coin I made not too long ago with a market id on radydium that I never used (it’s all in my account), now I want to make another coin but I don’t wanna pay for another market id, so I tried to change the metadata but it’s immutable. If there is any way to change immutable metadata it’d perfect. If not, I thought about another solution but I don’t know if possible and I don’t know how: remove the old coin from the market id and put the new coin under this market id instead.
Let me know what is possible and if you can also explain I’ll be grateful, thanks

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think once the metadata immutable parameter is pushed there is no way to make it mutable and change the metadata.
Only if the token would be created with mutable metadata then you could perform an update from the metadata account.

Yes that’s what I thought. But is there any way to take the market id from this coin and use it for a new coin?
